# Did Heidegger talk about malice at all?

Tags: ethics, nietzsche, heidegger, good-and-evil, foucault

Did Heidegger talk about malice at all?

I agree and find interesting if not useful most of Nietzsche's aphorisms but felt that his analysis of malice was just weak, and obviously so. However, I liked the article by Foucault, on Nietzsche, where he suggests that seeking knowledge is malicious or perhaps even the source of our malice. I'd be interested in any articles that add to that, especially in terms of genealogy.

But to get started I first want to know if Heidegger talked about malice at all. I found his 'authenticity' a little vacuous even if seductive, and thought it might be a good place to start because of Nietzsche's influence on this major philosopher, and because I associated authenticity with dissociation, which Foucault links to genealogical histories.

Comment: First off, welcome to philosophy.SE. There's something really unclear in your question where I'm not seeing the connection between most of what you want to write and the final question about Heidegger you seem to want to ask... Can you edit your question to make it clear?

Comment: Welcome, Luke! I guess your line of thought is that since Foucault, writing about Nietzsche, carves out accounts of malice in Nietzsche and Heidegger also wrote about and was influenced by Nietzsche, the same might hold true for Heidegger as well? In other words, you ask whether Heidegger has accounts of malice in Nietzschean themes or terms? If so, it might help to give the first part about Foucault complementing the lack of Nietzsche being explicit about malice as context and put the bridge to Heidegger and the explicit question about Heidegger into a separate paragraph.